# Unwrap a BTreeSet in rust

Tags: rust

In rust, the following function is legal:

```rust
fn unwrap<T>(s:Option<T>) -> T {
    s.unwrap()
}
```

It takes ownership of `s`, panics if it is a `None`, and returns ownership of the contents of `s` (which is legal since an `Option` owns its contents).

I was trying to write a similar function with signature

```rust
fn unwrap_set<T>(s: BTreeSet<T>) -> T { 
  ...
}
```

The idea is that it panics unless `s` has size 1, in which case it returns the single element. It seems like this should be possible for the same reason `unwrap` is possible, however none of the methods on `BTreeSet` had the right signature (they would need to have return type `T`). The closest was `take`, and I tried to do

```rust
    let mut s2 = s;
    let v: &T = s2.iter().next().unwrap();
    s2.take(v).unwrap()
```

but this failed.

Is writing a function like `unwrap_set` possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to use [`BTreeSet<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeSet.html)'s implementation of [`IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html), which would allow you to easily pull owned values out of the set one at a time:

```rust
fn unwrap_set<T>(s: BTreeSet<T>) -> T {
    let mut it = s.into_iter();
    if let Some(first) = it.next() {
        if let None = it.next() {
            return first;
        }
    }
    panic!("set must have a single value");
}
```

If you wanted to indirectly rely on `IntoIterator` you could also use a normal loop, but I don't think it's as readable that way so I probably wouldn't do this:

```rust
fn unwrap_set<T>(s: BTreeSet<T>) -> T {
    let mut result = None;
    for item in s {
        // If there is a second value, bail out
        if let Some(_) = result {
            result = None;
            break;
        }
        result = Some(item);
    }
    return result.expect("set must have a single value");
}
```

Comment: thanks! I didn't realise `into_iter` was more powerful than `iter` in this way

Comment: @xuanji if you need the ownership of the elements yes `into_iter` is the key. Here is an alternative solution with a functional way : https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=abf2955995b9d6049dba07ab8f839dd0